# Delete ^C in CTRL-C handling

Tags: c, unix, signals

I have code to handle the ctrl-c signal:

```
void    signal_ctrl_c(void)
{
    int pid;

    pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
    if (pid)
    {
        ft_putendl_fd("\b\b  \b\b", 1); //this function just prints and go to new line
        ft_putstr_fd("DUDE->", 1); // just prints
    }
}
```

So, when I try to use ctrl-c in this case I have ^C before my own shell's name^ and my question is - how to delete ^C?

Case is:
DUDE->ls > a | cat
*there I use ctrl-c*
^CDUDE->

Thanks a lot for answers!

Comment: When I type "ls > a | cat" and use ctrl-c   I get this ^Cownshell->

Comment: If you want to add information to your question then we would prefer that you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65424728/edit) it in, rather than appending a comment.  It is easier to find that way, and it persists in a findable place in the event that comments are deleted or moved to chat.

Comment: @JohnBollinger my bad, sorry, change it

Comment: Thank you.  I'm pretty confident that it's the host shell from which you launch your program that is printing the "^C" characters, not your program itself.  In that case, avoiding that would probably require putting your program in a separate process group from that shell.  But I'm afraid I don't have the time to write up a full answer about that, and it is more complicated than it might sound.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In default cases like DUDE->*ctrl-c* I get new line and DUDE-> without ^C. Because I use \b. I thought that you can get rid of it in the same way. Anyway thanks a lot for answer!

Comment: Send it a SIGTERM or SIGQUIT, and you wont see the ^C. The ^C is a TTY artefact.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I will fix it with ft_putstr_fd("\b\b  \b\b", 1); before my IF condition.